# How Can I Display Data on same page after clicking radio button in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have two Div section, One Div section contains list of radio button, I want to when i click the radio button, display the data corresponding to radio button on another Div section.

```
<div class="card-body ">
  <form id="ShowAvailableDataFiles" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      <input type="radio" id="showavailabledataid" name="datafilesname" value='{{ post }}'
             onclick="ShowAvailableDataFiles()"> {{ post }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
  </form>
</div>

<div id='show-me'>
{% for data in datas %}
    {{data}}
{% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
  function ShowAvailableDataFiles() {
    $('#showavailabledataid').on('click', function () {
      var radioValue = $("input[name='showavailabledataname']:checked").val();
      console.log("You clicked radio button")
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "/analytics/datafile_name/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        datafiles: $("input[name='showavailabledataname']:checked").val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("=========")

      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please explain with sample data how you want to populate div values.

Comment: suppose radio button with country name like(o  India), and when we click on radio button(o of india) It display New Delhi and so on on another div which is 'show-me'

Comment: in your `success` function, after `console.log("===")`, just fill the contents of your div with the data. e.g. `$('#show-me').text(data.cities)` or probably you'll want to go through a for loop to add the cities to the div as <li> elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax's success function:

```
success: function (data) {
        html_code = "<input type='checkbox' id='filesid' name = 'filesname' value='"+data+"'>"+data+"<br>"
        $('#show-me').html(html_code);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Put a debugger; inside success function and analyze if your data is coming properly. Also, data.val was just a representation of the model's value. So it can be data.model_field

Comment: Data is coming properly, but didn't show with checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="filesid"  name = "filesname" value= '{{data}}' > {{data}} <br>

Comment: Edited the answer to support your checkbox insertion dynamically.

Comment: @Pratap you can't use django template variables!!! javascript is executed in the browser, so there's not django running to evaluate your template. This is just HTML and javascript.

Comment: right now checkbox is showing with +data+ instead of actual data. alert(data['data')) alert correct value but didn't display with checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#showavailabledataid').on('click', function() {
    const val = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    $('#show-me').text(val);
});
```

Comment: data comes from views not any constant data